# Identity element in non-associative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, associativity

It is said, that if both a left identity and a right identity in associative ring exists, then it is a two-sided identity as $$e_1=e_1*e_2=e_2$$
Why is associativity required for this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody said associativity was required.

You can search the web and find the phrase "nonassociative ring with unity" used, and see their examples.

In fact, I think you can just take any nonassociative ring $R$ and perform the standard [Dorroh construction](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Dorroh_Extension) on $\mathbb Z\times R$ to get a nonassociative ring with identity.